# How do I reassign a random choice?

Tags: python, random

Currently at startup my code randomly assigns a user agent from a large list; what I'm not sure how to do, is to reassign that choice at a certain function further down.

```
  randomAgent =  random.choice(user_agent_list)
  headers = {'User-Agent': randomAgent}
```

This is currently what chooses randomly from the list of user-agents.

Comment: What do you mean by 'reassign' ? Reuse the same ?

Comment: Why can't you just run those two lines of code again?  It will make a new random selection.

Comment: Can you add a MRE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You just have to call the random function again later in your code. Example below.

```
randomAgent =  random.choice(user_agent_list)
headers = {'User-Agent': randomAgent}

# Later in code
randomAgent =  random.choice(user_agent_list)
headers = {'User-Agent': randomAgent}

# Or
headers = {'User-Agent': random.choice(user_agent_list)}
```